# Leveraging XSD to Validate Data prior to XML Post via Web Service

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, web-services, xsd

I am writing a service that reads a string of comma delimited values (and their labels) from memory and packages them into an XML file to send. An associated XSD file is being generated by the data owner with each XML structure. I would like to read and XSD file to validate a list of data labels in a `.txt` file prior to posting the XML via web service. If a descrepancy is detected between the XSD and txt file, I'd like the code to throw an exception. On a successful match, it takes the values from the `.txt` file, packages, and posts the XML request. I am looking for an example of the entire process (from input to output) of how this could be done.

Read an input file and collect attributes and values (TestValuesIN.txt)

```
 "test.Foo", 122;
```

Open an XSD file and perform a one-to-one match on the elements against my input file's list of elements. For now I only care about "Test.Foo" (element: Test.Foo val:) existing in the XSD. (TextXSD.xsd)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Generated using Flame-Ware Solutions XML-2-XSD v2.0 at http://www.flame-ware.com/Products/XML-2-XSD/ -->
<xs:schema id="batch-execution" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="batch-execution" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="insert">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="test.Foo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="val" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="fire-all-rules">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="get-objects">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="out-identifier" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then Post the XML to

```
http://mycamelhump.<myurl>.com:8080/drools-camel-service/kservice/CommTestXML/execute
```

URI

```
<batch-execution>
 <insert>
  <test.Foo>
    <val>122</val>
  </test.Foo>
</insert>
<fire-all-rules max="-1"/>
<get-objects out-identifier="also-foo"/>
</batch-execution>
```

The code gets the results prints the output to (TestValuesOUT.txt)

```
"Test.Foo", 100;
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Thanks Walther. In the heat of writing the post I missed the question.

Comment: So do you want to validate the contents of the CSV file, before converting it to XML?  Is that what you're asking for an example of?

Comment: That's correct. A rudementary check of a list of objects from the .txt file vs. the objects in the .xsd file by label. ("Test.Foo"), and to throw and error if there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to build the xml doc and use .NET XML schemaset to validate your xml before you post it to your web service - like this:

```
public List<string> ValidateXml(string xml, string rootXsdName)
    {
        List<string> xsdValidationErrors = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            // Note: Don't use XDocument schema validation as this will give a false positive of a string without XSD specified       
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += ((o, e) => xsdValidationErrors.Add(e.Message));
            settings.Schemas = GetXmlSchemas(rootXsdName);

            TextReader textReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings);

            // Parse the file.          
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Empty control loop to read through entire document getting errors uaing ValidationEventHandler
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            xsdValidationErrors.Add("Unable to parse XML");
        }


        return xsdValidationErrors;
    }
```

And the implementation of GetXmlSchemas will look like this...

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Generates an XmlSchema set to use to validate the xDocument
    /// </summary>
    private XmlSchemaSet GetXmlSchemas(string xsdFileName)
    {
        XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();

        // ... build the schema set here

        return schemas;
    }
```

So - GetXmlSchemaSet will load in all you xsd files (if you have multiple files)

HTH

Comment: Good question Jay. Our rules engine's XSD does not marry our XML out. The XSD reflects the way the beans are arranged in Apache while the XML is for us .NET coders to package and send messages to. I wanted to kill 2 birds with one stone by reading in the ASD and comparing it to the input file. This will always tell me if something is not right with the XML schema. This "code-around" is a temporary fix until we can get JAXb to generate XML in accordance to the ASD file.